Парсер всех картинок на странице Vk
Я бы хотел узнать, возможно ли создать парсер страниц в ВК, который бы вытягивал все изображения пользователя (аватарка, стена, сохраненные фотографии и тд) чтобы их, к примеру, прогонять через нейронку? Понимаю, что это звучит как-то не очень, но если картинки в открытом доступе и будут обрабатываться автономно, то почему бы и нет. Интересует технический момент, возможно ли такое сделать (на питоне например)? Просто опыта в написании парсеров пока нет, хотел бы узнать в какую сторону копать.

Ну копайте в сторону api. Пока это один из приемлемых вариантов

Как упомянул в комментарии @Алексей Шиманский, копать нужно в сторону http api этого сервиса, это будет самый адекватный вариант(но не единственный) Однако стоит понимать, что тут речь идёт не об официальном api, документацию по которой предоставляет VK открыто. ВК официально не предоставляет api для управления страницами вк, а тут именно тот случай, когда это нужно.
Ренкомендую эту библиотеку:
https://github.com/python273/vk_api - это обертка для работы с api вконтакте из под личной страницы.Разработана на базе библиотеки requests. У этой библиотеки есть комьюнити, загляните сюда и задайте вопросы если что то не выходит: https://t.me/python273_vk_api
Так же не лишним будет ознакомиться с библиотекой requests: https://pypi.org/project/requests/
Есть способ по сложнее в реализации, который будет работать медленнее, но это универсальный способ парсинга практически с любого веб-ресурса. Речь идёт об управлении браузером в автоматическом режиме. Для этого можно использовать selenium: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/ , хотя я бы рекомендовал использовать playwright https://playwright.dev/python/docs/intro в качестве альтернативы selenium.

А зачем тут «управление страницами вк»?

@andreymal да, звучит парадоксально, однако так будет на много проще юзать методы получения картинок других юзеров (из под реальной страницы юзать апи) Там как бы и методы и сама либа к этому распологает, хотя заюзав чистый requests точно можно и без этого обойтись, просто жизнь себе усложните тогда. Это чисто со своего опыта говорю, потому что работал с этой либой и апишкой вк в целом.
